# Change the tab size in Android Studio's default Tabbed Activity

Tags: android, tabs

I am using Android Studio 2.2.2, and have loaded their default tabbed activity.

I wish to create an activity with 5 tabs in such a way that only 3 tabs are displayed at a time and the new ones reveal themselves on scrolling.

Here's what I am getting:

[image: The 5 tabs are all cramped up]

How do I ensure only 3 sections are displayed at a time?

(Please ask which part of the code is required)

Comment: Use `app:tabMode="scrollable"` in the TabLayout, it will get it close to what you want.  I don't think you can control how many Tabs are displayed at a time, but the Tabs will reveal themselves on swiping the ViewPager (or scrolling inside the TabLayout).

Comment: This resolved the problem, thanks a ton :)